# How to trigger 'quirks mode' is IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode

**Background**:

The issue I'm facing is actually related to printing a webpage. The page is (almost) valid HTML 5 (with a few `<table>`s with `cellpadding`, and some `<img>`s without `alt`s etc). I have a print stylesheet that prints nicely in all the browsers we are supposed to support (latest Chrome, FF and IE) except IE 10.

We have specific requirements about the print layout (which is significantly different from the web layout). We cannot use a separate page designed for printing as most of the page's content is generated using lots of inputs from the user within JavaScript. One of our print layout requirements is that the printout be on exactly 3 pages with specific parts on specific pages. Its working in all browsers we are supporting except IE 10.

In IE 10, the print out is 6 pages (3 in all others) working with the standard "Shrink To Fit" setting. Now I could go around writing a separate print stylesheet for IE 10 but that just seems like too much work.

While playing around with the IE 10 dev tools, I noticed that if I select "Quirks" "Document Mode" and then print, it fits nicely in 3 pages. So the simplest solution to my printing problem seems to be to somehow trigger quirks mode in IE 10 (but not in IE 11 where it already works).

**The actual question**:

So the question is, how do I trigger quirks mode in IE 10 without triggering it in IE > 10. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN page says

> If a page doesn't contain a `<!DOCTYPE>` directive, Internet Explorer displays the page in quirks mode by default.

So I tried doing the following with my doctype declaration:

```
<!--[if gt IE 10]>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<![endif]-->
```

That didn't trigger quriks mode in IE 10 for me. What will?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a meta tag to controll how the page should render:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
```

This will cause the page to be rendered in IE10 mode if a `DOCTYPE` is present  otherwise it will fallback to quirksmode. You can check [this link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see the different `X-UA-Compatible` modes that can be used.

So if you want IE10 to always render the page in quirksmode you ought to be able to force it using:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```